# How to work with Laravel Authorization having roles to users

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a system to control finals period's and I have some users, roles and rules:

- Users:

  - Student
  - Professor
  - Coordinator

In table `users` I created a column `permissions` that receive a number to identify his role:

- Roles:

  - Student = 8
  - Professor = between 1 and 7
  - Coordinator = 9

**How I create Gates and policies to organize authorizations** having some rules:

1. Student and Professor only can see their final period and send files who they are associated.
2. Coordinator is a "admin", can create/edit/delete on any table.

[image: Database]

Answer (score 0):

For ACL in Laravel, you may try this package: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust. The documentation is pretty clear there.